# VScodeで正常に例外がスローされなくなりました

Tags: python, python3, vscode

### 環境

Windows 10 Pro
VSCode 1.63.0
Python 3.9.6

### 現状

・VScodeでは例外が正常にキャッチできません。（以前はできていました。）
・コマンドプロンプトでスクリプト直接実行すると正常に実行できます。
・PyScripterでは正常に実行できます。
・例にあげたスクリプト以外でも例外が正常にキャッチできません。

VScodeにおいて、デバッグ実行(F5)で実行する際に、例外が正常に機能しない状態で、デバッグなし実行では正常な結果を出力することから、該当する例外スロー部分は正常に機能しているという意味です。また、このような動作になったのは最近のことで、以前はこのような動作ではなく、デバッグ実行でも正常な結果でした。

venvによる仮想環境でのデバッグ実行で現象が発生することが分かりました。venvではない環境で同じバージョンのpythonによりデバッグ実行した場合には、正常に動作することが分かりました。

VScodeで正常に例外キャッチさせるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

### スクリプト

以下のpythonスクリプトを例として記述しますが、以前は正常に動作していたスクリプトです。
アプリケーションから起動するサーバーのip address:portが既にOpenしているかを確認するものです。

`except socket.timeout` の部分で例外をキャッチして判断します。

以前は、この例外キャッチできてしました。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" class_NetworkPort.py
FileName:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class_NetworkPort.py

Description:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ネットワークのポートをチェックします。

History:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2020/12/21 作成

"""

import socket
import ipaddress

UDP = 'UDP'
TCP = 'TCP'
IPv4 = socket.AF_INET

class class_NetworkPort():
    def __init__(self):
        """初期化　ソケットのタイムアウト値を設定します。
        """
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

    def chk_address_port(self,ip_address:str,port_number:int):
        if not isinstance(port_number,int):
            return
        else:
            if port_number == 0 or port_number > 65535:
                return
        if isinstance(ip_address,str):
            try:
                _address_ = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_address)
                if _address_ is not None:
                    if _address_.is_multicast \
                        or _address_.is_reserved \
                        or _address_.version != 4:
                        return
                else:
                    return

            except ipaddress.AddressValueError:
                return
        else:
            return

        return True

    def check_localhost(self,ip_address):
        """自機に割り振られたIPv4アドレスかどうかを確認します。

        Args:
            ip_address ([str]):IPv4アドレス文字列、マルチキャストや予約済みアドレスは禁止。
        Returns:
            [bool]: 自機アドレスならTrue
        """

        ip_list = list()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        hostname, _ , ip_list = socket.gethostbyname_ex(host)

        _,_,localhost = socket.gethostbyname_ex('localhost')
        ip_list.extend(localhost)

        if ip_address in ip_list:
            return True

        return False

    def check_bind_port(self,ip_address:str,protocol_type:str,port_number:int):
        """自機のPCにバインドできるポートであるか確認

        Args:
            ip_address (str):IPv4アドレス文字列、マルチキャストや予約済みアドレスは禁止。
            protocol_type (str): TCP/UDP
            port_number (int): ポート番号0以外の65535以下のポート番号
        Returns:
            [bool]: 変数の違反ならNone,バインドできなければFalse、バインド成功ならTrue
        """

        isOK = False
        if protocol_type != UDP and protocol_type != TCP:
            return
        else:
            if protocol_type == UDP:
                _ptype_ = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
            if protocol_type == TCP:
                _ptype_ = socket.SOCK_STREAM

        try:
            isOK = self.chk_address_port(ip_address,port_number,)
        except ipaddress.AddressValueError as e:
            raise e

        _chk_socket_ = socket.socket(IPv4,_ptype_)

        try:
            _chk_socket_.bind((ip_address,port_number))
            isOK = True
        except OSError:
            isOK = False

        _chk_socket_.close()

        return isOK

    def check_connect_port(self,ip_address:str,protocol_type:str,port_number:int):
        """接続先のTCPポートに接続できるかを確認。

        Args:
            ip_address (str):IPv4アドレス文字列、マルチキャストや予約済みアドレスは禁止。
            protocol_type (str): TCP
            port_number (int): ポート番号0以外の65535以下のポート番号
        Returns:
            [bool]: 変数の違反ならNone,接続できなければFalse、接続成功ならTrue
        """

        isOK = False
        if protocol_type != TCP:
            return
        else:
            if protocol_type == TCP:
                _ptype_ = socket.SOCK_STREAM
        try:
            isOK = self.chk_address_port(ip_address,port_number,)
        except ipaddress.AddressValueError as e:
            raise e

        _chk_socket_ = socket.socket(IPv4,_ptype_)

        try:
            _chk_socket_.connect((ip_address,port_number))
            isOK = True
        except socket.timeout:
            isOK = False
        except OSError:
            isOK = False

        _chk_socket_.close()

        return isOK


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instNW = class_NetworkPort()

    ip_address = '127.0.0.1'
    protocol_type = TCP
    port_number = [8080,6970]

    for i in port_number:
        if instNW.check_connect_port(
            ip_address = ip_address,
            protocol_type = protocol_type,
            port_number= i
            ):
            print('ソケット接続成功　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))
        else:
            print('XXXXソケット失敗XXXX　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))


    if instNW.check_localhost(ip_address=ip_address):
        for i in range(1024):
            if instNW.check_bind_port(
                ip_address = ip_address,
                protocol_type = protocol_type,
                port_number= i
                ):
                print('バインド成功　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))
            else:
                print('XXXXバインド失敗XXXX　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))
    else:
        for i in range(1024):
            if instNW.check_connect_port(
                ip_address = ip_address,
                protocol_type = protocol_type,
                port_number= i
                ):
                print('ソケット接続成功　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))
            else:
                print('XXXXソケット失敗XXXX　{} {}:{}'.format(ip_address,protocol_type,i))
```

### VScode のエラー出力

現在のVScode上でのエラー出力は以下のようになります。

```
例外が発生しました: timeout
timed out
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\プロジェクトフォルダ\class_NetworkPort.py", line 139, in check_connect_port
    _chk_socket_.connect((ip_address,port_number))
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\プロジェクトフォルダ\class_NetworkPort.py", line 159, in <module>
    if instNW.check_connect_port(
```

モジュール名socketが認識されていない？ようです。
このため、
except socket.timeout　→　except timeout
としてみましたが、timeoutでは認識できませんでした。

Comment: VS Code で、と質問文に書かれていますが、VS Code は関係なくて、単に Python の try ... except ... が想定した通りに動かなくなった、という質問内容だと解釈して間違っていないでしょうか？　VS Code 以外だと「正常に実行できる」というのが、try ... except ... の部分で例外が except 側でキャッチできているという意味なのか、そもそも例外が出ていないという意味なのかで状況が変わってきそうだなと思っています。

Comment: vscodeで指定しているインタプリタがターミナルのものと違うような気がします。ターミナルから`python --version`したものと、コード内で`import sys` `print(sys.version)`したものが同じか確認してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。さらに判明したことを含め記述を追加しました。python -Vとsys.versionは同じでした。Vscodeのvenv環境下でのデバッグ実行において、同現象が発生することが分かりました。venv環境でない場合には発生しません。また、venv環境下でデバックなし実行でも発生しません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決したので記載します。

## 結論

VScodeを完全消去し、再度環境構築をした結果、正常になりました。
VScodeの環境が何らかの影響で破壊されていた可能性が高いです。

## これまでの経緯

・cloneした別環境のPCでは正常に動作した。
・以前に突如VScodeが起動しなくなり、完全消去ではない再インストールしたことがあった。
・時折、VScode上でDELやBSキーが機能しなくなる現象があった。
これらのことから、該当現象が発生しているPC上のVScodeのみで何らかの不具合があると想定。

## 完全消去

１）プログラムと機能からVScodeをアンインストールする。
２）C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Roaming\Codeのフォルダをフォルダ全体を削除
３）C:\Users\ユーザー名.vscodeのフォルダをフォルダ全体を削除

## インストール

改めて、VScodeのインストーラでインストール
VScode拡張機能をインストール
※Python本体やpyenvなどの別途構築する環境は全く変更しておりません。